# GetLastError returning ERROR_SUCCESS after calling ConnectNamedPipe

Tags: winapi, pipe, named-pipes

When I call ConnectNamedPipe with an OVERLAPPED structure and check GetLastError afterwards, I often see GetLastError return ERROR_SUCCESS. The way I'm reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365146%28VS.85%29.aspx), that should never happen. My understanding is that if a client has already connected, ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED should be set, not ERROR_SUCCESS.

Has anyone else seen this? The OS is 32-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's typical for OVERLAPPED.  It tells whether the parameters are okay before connecting, assuming an asynchronous socket.  Once a connection completes or fails, then `GetOverlappedResult()` returns the proper status.  So I guess this is a minor documentation error.

Comment: So, to clarify, if GetLastError() returns ERROR_SUCCESS after ConnectNamedPipe(), I should treat it as ERROR_IO_PENDING and call GetOverlappedResult()?

Comment: Kind of.  It doesn't really mean the i/o is pending.  It could fail, for example if there is an improper IP address.  So i/o isn't pending.  It just hasn't occurred yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling GetLastError() immediately after ConnectNamedPipe.
Don't call any API in between.